# MVC Partial View and Models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a HomeController with this code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IndexModel m = new IndexModel();
    m.Test = "someString";

    m.LoginModel = new ViewLoginModel();
    m.LoginModel.Test = "FromLogin";

    return View("Login", m);
}
```

And in my Index.cshtml, I have this:

```
@model IndexModel

//bunch of HTML

@Html.Partial("_Login", Model.LoginModel)
```

And in the _Login.cshtml, this:

```
@model ViewLoginModel

//bunch of HTML

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Test)
```

Basically, what I want to do is to have a separate model for a partial window (login) in my home page, and this model can be or not a child of the ViewIndexModel (ideally this shouldn't even exist).
I'm trying to access the variables and write/use them in the partial view, but it doesn't work - it displays the property's name instead.

In the partial view "_Login", the intellisense also doesn't work for some reason (VS2013), although the @Html.BeginForm and stuff is working, but I can't access the model's properties.

What am I doing wrong, how do I fix this?

Also, is there a difference between these two?

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Home/_Login.cshtml")
@Html.Partial("Login")
```

It seems when I'm using #2 the function "Login" is being called in my HomeController, not sure why...

Comment: Html.Partial requires a function name that returns a partialView ! not a cshtml page name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it is displaying the property names is because you using an HTML helper that is designed to display the property names.

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Test)
```

To simply output the value of a property in a model, you can use this syntax

```
@model.Test
```

If you want to be able to edit it (assuming its a string), then wrap it in a TextBoxFor helper

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Test)
```

As for your second question, I would assume that without the fully qualified name of the view, that the routing engine is getting involved.  I have not tested this and typically use the fully qualified name to get that extra few milliseconds of speed from .NET not having to try and guess what view I am asking for.